# C# "hex shift" in binary file

Tags: c#, hex

Example (native GIF header):

GIF89a (47 49 46 38 39 61)

I want to read this file, and shift its hex content (--++ pattern)

FHG98` (46 48 47 39 38 60)

Comment: Then do it :-) Where is the problem? What have you tried so far? Is it homework?

Comment: Its easy to do. So what's the problem?

Comment: Why do people keep calling strings of bytes "hex"

Comment: No, it's not homework, but I'm totally new to programming. I know how to read file, get byte (byte y = b.ReadByte();)
How can I convert this to hex?

Comment: and BTW, shifting is something different

Comment: What do you mean "convert to hex"? A byte is a numeric value, the base in which it's displayed when you output it makes no difference. Go read about numeric bases!

Comment: @svick - I know, but my english is as bad as my programming skills ;)

@Matti - Because of "hex view" in my editor...

Comment: Also, the question arises... why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Lucero, no need to belittle someone that has a legitimate question

Comment: @matti - this is my second day with C#, and I wanted to do something... useful?:P I "decoded" a few jpegs from a game called Sproink, someone used this simple method to make files unreadable.

Comment: @cpalmer (and whoever it concerns), it was not my intention to belittle someone, but rather to find out what the author of the question was having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllBytes("output.dat", File.ReadAllBytes("input.dat")
                                     .Select((b,i)=> (byte)(i%4 < 2 ? b-1 : b+1))
                                     .ToArray());
```

Comment: some explanation for the user thats new to programming would be usefull. Unreadable lambda's won't help the user to understand it.